# Ember.js find() with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ember.js

I have an Rails API which responds with the following JSON:

**/users/1**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "sjobs@apple.com"
}
```

**/users/1?embed=role,store**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "sjobs@apple.com"
    "store": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Apple Store"
    },
    "role": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Owner"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to decide which relationships to fetch with Ember.js - App.User.find(1)? I've tried App.User.find({id: 1, embed: 'role'}) but it sends the GET request as /users?id=1&embed=role which routes to the index action in the Rails controller.

Is there a better way to handle this? I have full access to modify the API. Sideloading on every API request seems overkill, I would be great if I could decide relationships based on query params.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way to handle this?

I guess the best option assuming you are using the RESTAdapter should be to define your side-loading as embedded, for example:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.User', {
  role: { embedded: 'always' },
  store: { embedded: 'always' }
};
```

This way `role` and `store` are saved embedded in the same record and thus not resulting in separate GET requests.

The two possible values of embedded are:

**always:** The child records are embedded when loading, and are saved embedded in the same record.

**load:** The child records are embedded when loading, but should be saved as standalone records. In order for this to work, the child records must have an ID.

Hope it helps.